# Simultaneous key press bug

Tags: keyboard, laptop

I have a new Dell laptop (5480) running Ubuntu 17.04 and I have issues when I press two key simultaneously.

Indeed, one of the keys is not triggered. It is especially an issue for the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd> shortcuts (like opening a terminal or switching virtual desktop).

I can see it in the visual keyboard layout, one of the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> or <kbd>ALT</kbd> box doesn't light up. However, if I press another key the status of the keyboard is indeed updated.

So I have to press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> then <kbd>ALT</kbd> slightly later.

Here is the output of `lshw`:

```
*-firmware
      description: BIOS
      fabriquant: Dell Inc.
      identifiant matériel: 0
      version: 1.1.1
      date: 01/17/2017
      taille: 64KiB
      capacité: 15MiB
      fonctionnalités: pci pnp upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect edd int13floppynec int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb smartbattery biosbootspecification netboot uefi
```

Any idea on that?